# Quiz prints incorrect value for number of wrong guesses

Tags: python, scope, namespaces

I would like the following code to print the number of incorrect guesses entered by the program user in a simple quiz.

The current code prints `0` and no other values for the number of incorrect guesses. What's causing this behavior?

```
def new_game():
    wrong_guess = 0
    correct_guess = 0
    question_num = 1

    print("10-Question Automated Quiz")
    print("Developed by: Wesly Farillon")

    for key in questions:
        print("-------------------------------------------------")
        print("Question:", key)
        print("\nChoices:")
        for i in answers[question_num - 1]:
            print(i)
        guess = input("\nType your Answer here: ")
        guess = guess.upper()      

        correct_guess += check_answer(questions.get(key), guess, wrong_guess)
        question_num += 1

        print("Score: ", correct_guess)
        print("Wrong: ", wrong_guess)

def check_answer(answer, guess, wrong_guess):
    if answer == guess:
        return 1
    else:
        wrong_guess += 1
        return 0
        
questions = {"Which method can be used to replace parts of a string?" : "A", "Which statement is used to stop a loop?" : "B",
            "How do you start writing a while loop in Python?" : "A", "It refers to the spaces at the beginning of a code line" : "D"}

answers = [["A. replace()", "B. repl()", "C. switch()", "D. replacestring()"], ["A. stop", "B. break", "C. return", "D. exit"],
            ["A. while x < y:", "B. while (x < y)", "C. x < y while {", "D. while x < y {"], ["A. Syntax", "B. Comment", "C. Statement", "D. Indentation"]]

new_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't printing the number of wrong guesses accurately because it's not incrementing the variable it prints the value of.

Thanks to Marcin for pointing out that there's a distinction between Python namespaces and scopes: a namespace is "a mapping from names to objects," usually a Python dictionary, and many things have namespaces associated with them - modules and functions, for example. A scope is "a textual region of a Python program where a namespace is directly accessible." As you can imagine, it's possible for a scope to encompass many namespaces. [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

This code increments a variable called `wrong_guess` that's defined in the scope of the `check_answer` function and lives in the `check_answer` namespace. When you call `check_answer`, this `wrong_guess` variable is assigned an initial value equal to the value of the `wrong_guess` variable defined in the scope of the `new_game` function (that lives in the `new_game` namespace). These `wrong_guess` variables have the same name, but they exist in different namespaces and they're *not* the same variable.

The code prints the value of the variable `wrong_guess` defined in the scope of the `new_game` function, and boom - you have your undesired behavior where the printed number of inaccurate guesses fails to increment.

Note that even though the `wrong_guess` in the `check_answer` namespace increments when wrong answers are entered, the value of that `wrong_guess` variable is also being set to 0 (the value of the other `wrong_guess` variable in the `new_game` namespace) every time the code runs `check_answer`, for the same reason described above. That function call is inside `new_game` and uses the `wrong_answer` found in the local `new_game` scope (value `0`) to provide an argument to `check_answer`.

See from Real Python: Namespaces and Scope in Python [[2]](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/)

Comment: FYI `namespace` is not the same same `scooe` is

Comment: That's a good point @Ma

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and correct that?

Comment: Oops, entered before finished typing. I meant to say "That's a good point @MarcinOrlowski, let me do a little reading and expand the answer." In this example I still believe it's accurate to say either that there's a namespace discrepancy or a scope discrepancy (between the variable being incremented and the variable being printed). I'll be mindful about the difference between an actual namespace dictionary and the textual scope that accesses namespace dictionaries.